# MongoDB - How to remove part of field with $unset

Tags: arrays, mongodb, unset

I have a database in MongoDB where there are entries with the following structure [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlZCV.png)

I am using a script in Python that I use to retrive information from this strucutre and then saves it to a csv.

The end goal is to remove ONLY SOME parts of the `parameters` structure. For instance, I want to keep `parameters[0].values` and `parameters[1].values` but not `parameters[2:5].values`

I am not experienced in this but the command I am using is the following

`{"$unset":"exercises.parameters.values"] }`

but this will remove all `values` from all the objects inside `parameters`. Since the variable has the same name amongst the objects I can't find a way to specify which ones I want.

I have also tried indexing like so

`{"$unset":"exercises.parameters[2].values"] }`

but that doesn't seem to work...

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**update**

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": 1
},
{
  "$unset": {
    "exercises.$[].parameters.2.values": "",
    "exercises.$[].parameters.3.values": "",
    "exercises.$[].parameters.4.values": "",
    "exercises.$[].parameters.5.values": ""
  }
},
{
  "multi": true
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J2nDtBIx8tI)

---

**aggregate**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "exercises": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$exercises",
          "as": "item",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$item",
              {
                parameters: {
                  $slice: [ "$$item.parameters", 2 ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TaLvYRUkWxc)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did not know about mongo playground that is really helpful. I can see that your example works but it is using `update` however I am using `aggregate` since I do not want to change the database just fetch data from it. I've tried to change the code to use `aggregate` but I always get the error "Invalid $unset :: caused by :: FieldPath field names may not start with '$'. Consider using $getField or $setField." Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @GonçaloChambel I update my answer with `$aggregate`

Comment: thanks a lot it worked!